# How to set and use property in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm learning Kotlin. I thought the variables setted on the constructor were properties of the class, but I think I was wrong so I'm setting the variable using `init`:

```
class JNI(val _context: Context) {
    var context: Context;
    init {
        this.context = _context;
    }
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        private fun loadWavAsset(assetMgr: AssetManager, assetName: String, index: String, pan: Float): Boolean {

           
            val myAssetPath : String = "assets/my_asset"
            val assetLookupKey =  FlutterLoader.getInstance().getLookupKeyForAsset(myAssetPath)
            val inputStream: InputStream = context.assets.open(assetLookupKey)
```

Well, even with this, the line `val inputStream: InputStream = context.assets.open(assetLookupKey)` gives error saying there's no `context` object.

How can I set the context object then?

Comment: You cannot use class properties in a static context. That is true for any object-oriented language like Java, C#, etc

Comment: @KyzerSoze I meant the `context` to be static. What if I put it inside the companion?

Comment: you will need to add `context` as a parameter to your function `loadWavAsset`.

Comment: If you want to use static methods only, you don't need the class. Use an `object` instead and get rid of the `companion`. And as mentioned above, you'll have to pass your context value as a parameter of your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classes exist as instances. They can be created and destroyed, and there can be many instances of the same class.

The companion object of a class is static. It is not tied to any particular instance of a class. It is accessible at all times from anywhere.

The `context` variable in your code, cannot be accessed from the companion object, as the variable is defined on the class instance.